# [[:digit:]] Equivalent for characters bash

Tags: regex, bash

What is the regex identifier for alpha characters equivalent to [[:digit:]] for numbers used within bash?  My man page scrubbing skills aren't very good today.

Comment: `| egrep "[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}"`
What I use for checking if IP, I would like this for alpha characters.

`| egrep "[[:alpha:]]{4}\.[[:alpha:]]{4}\.[[:alpha:]]{4}\.[[:alpha:]]{4}"`
However not sure of what that identifier is.

Comment: @HaydenSmith : You can't use your first `regex` to check ips by the way. If would give  false positive for `999.852.23.155` for instance. Hope you're working on data which is assumed to contain only valid ip addresses..

Comment: @sjsam Correct, it will only ever be passed valid IPs, or those IPs will be grabbed from nslookup against a hostname.  Less functionality but it's not needed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you correctly, you need the `character class` for alphabets which is

```
[[:alpha:]]
```

and if you're looking for anything other than an alphabet, then

```
[^[:alpha:]] # well the ^ in the beginning of a range negates it
```

This [[ **article** ]](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html) is an excellent read on Regex.

To grab the **valid** ip addresses from a file or input, i would use the below technique:

```
$ cat testfile.ip
Well this is a small para on IP addresses. Well to start with a string 
like 172.217.26.206 represents an IP address. Well, in this case it
is Google's IP. To put it short an IP like 192.168.0.16 is the token by
which a computer connected to internet is known to the outside wolrd. It 
is all numbers game! Really ! But as humans can't remember such crazy
numbers, some fellow devised a mechanism whereby we can call a computer 
by names like 'puppy' or 'vodoo'. This mechanism is called the DNS system 
whereby a computer is in charge of redirecting you to '192.168.0.34' in 
case you asked for 'vodoo' and '192.168.234.255' in case you asked for 
'puppy'. Well you've gateways as if you're going into some big cities. So 
you'll often here "You have the wrong gateway, mine is the right one 
which is 192.168.0.1." Well you have IPV6 addresses which are evern 
crazier numbers. Also, you do have wrong IP addresses like 
'288.134.43.22' and '999.1.0.255'. Aha ! You're in no man's land if you 
are assigned these IPS. Oh ! are you an alien? Sounds scary. Aww. Bye
$ grep -oP '[\d]{0,3}\.[\d]{0,3}\.[\d]{0,3}\.[\d]{0,3}' testfile.ip |
awk -v FS="." '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
if($i>=0 && $i<=255){continue;}else{next;}
}}1'
172.217.26.206
192.168.0.16
192.168.0.34
192.168.234.255
192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Appreciate it, away from my machine but wanted to verify this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- `man bash` and search for "regular expression" leads to a paragraph that points to **regex(3)**
- `man 3 regex` section "SEE ALSO" points to **regex(7)**
- `man 7 regex` lists the available character classes, including **digit** and, what you're after, **alpha**

Comment: "Teaching to fish" is something not seen enough around here!

Comment: Very true, on mobile so I was limited to online references to man pages.  Will look around on my machine and learn myself some character classes.